# boot menu kernel header update

Tags: grub2

i recently updated my ubuntu from 11.04 to 11.10 today, in this i know that it is with kernel 3.0 now after installation when i rebooted my system.i had the same old kernel 2.6.38.8... so i dig in to it and found out that my boot menu was not getting updated!! then i saw my /boot dir and found that i had 2.6.38.11 and 3.0.0.0-12 all versions but my grub2 is not updating boot menu!! what to do? i tried boot-repair,grub customizer and also reinstalled grub2 but i m still unable to fix this issue!! so can u suggest any solution
and yes i m not very command line friendly :)

hint:- i tried command

`sudo update-grub`

and

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

but both say "syntax error"

DOUBT:- i experimented BURGE boot-loader 7 to 8 months back!!was working well but it broke my plymouth so i removed it.but i think since then my kernel header is not being updated!! so could it be the coz of my problem? :)

sorry4such long post,but i thought this details might help u find some solutions thanks bye.. :(

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that could be the problem.
BURG overwrite your GRUB configuration in MBR and so you MUST repair it to make it work again.

You should repair your grub following this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) (also if you didn't install Windows) and then everything will be fine.